# Не определяет модуль graph pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Free pascal 2.4.4 с оф сайта(нужно сделать именно в нем). Что исправить в папке программы?

> 2.10 fatal can't find unit graph used by program

Comment: **Настроить пути до нужных папок нужно!**

Comment: Как Настроить пути до нужных папок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть второй вариант (я им всегда пользовался): скопировать папку с модулем Graph (Каталог, в котором установлен Паскаль  Units  graph) в папку Bin (туда, где лежит экзешник Паскаля) и написать такой код:

```
Uses
  CRT, Graph;

Var
  GraphDriver, GraphMode: Integer;

Begin
  GraphDriver:=Detect;
// папку можно и не копировать, а написать третьим параметром путь
  InitGraph(GraphDriver, GraphMode, 'graph\');

  SetColor(Red);
  Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 300);

  ReadLn;

  CloseGraph;
End.
```