# Pascal, модуль GRAPH, проблема при запуске .ехе с чужого компьютера

Tags: pascal

Подскажите пожалуйста:
Написал программу на паскале использущую модуль GRAPH, компилировал как в TP7.0 так и в FP2.2.0 все компилируется, все отлично:) и работает все у меня хорошо, но когда скидываю .exe другу, то у него не работает именно графический режим, как исправить? наверн надо еще какой-то файл) Причем у всех друзей) т.е. не только у одного)
код инициализации графики:

```
procedure InitG;
var
GraphDriver, GraphMode: Integer;
begin
   GraphDriver := detect;
   GraphMode := detect;
   InitGraph(GraphDriver, GraphMode, '');
   SetBkColor(white);
   SetViewPort(0, 0, GetMaxX, GetMaxY, ClipOn);
   cx := GetMaxX shr 1;
   cy := GetMaxY shr 1;
   ClearViewPort;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте папку в каталоге с программой (например, graph), а туда поместите модуль graph.tpu (расширение Турбо Паскаля (оно может быть и другим)), и напишите эту строку:

```
InitGraph(GraphDriver, GraphMode, 'graph\');
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65071/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-graph-pascal).

Answer (score 2):

нужен файл graph.bgi

Answer (score 0):

ну скинь ему файл graph.lib или как он там называется, он в папке UNIT обычно лежит, чесно не помню как он точно называется, погляди в папке.

А друг пусть этот файл скинет в корень где программа должна выполняться.

И будет счастье.

И еще а разве не нужно писать

```
Uses Graph;
```

Comment: procedure InitG;
это не вся программа) только процедура, которая инициализирует графику:)
Спасибо за совет:)